# Replicating proc logistic SAS to logistic regression in Python has issues (Intercept and one of the variable coefficient do not match)

Tags: python, sas, regression, logistic-regression

I have researched on how to replicate proc logistic from SAS to Logistic Regression in Python and come up with the following observations:

1. SAS uses unpenalized regression and python uses penalty=l2 by default. So I have changed it to penalty=none.
2. SAS has default convergence criteria GCONV=1E-8. Python has default value for convergence criteria with tol= 1e-4. I have updated it to 1e-8.
3. I have used solver=lbfgs (default value in Python).

According to the articles that I have found online, the parameter changes 1 and 2 should get the intercept and coefficient outputs for all model variables similar upto few decimal points in SAS and Python implementations.

**SAS code:**

```
proc logistic DESCENDING data=dataset_name;
model target_var=&modelvariables/ selection = none CLPARM=WALD lackfit RSQ STB ;
output out=result p=pred;
run;
```

**Python code:**

```
clf=LogisticRegression(penalty='none',solver='lbfgs',tol=0.00000001)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

When I compare the SAS and Python outputs, I am having an issue as the intercepts have difference of 2 and one of the variable has the coefficient with opposite sign.

*Example:*

*Intercept:* SAS (-7.03), Python (-5.21)
*Coefficient for one of the variable:* SAS (2.56), Python (-2.45)

The remaining variable coefficients match if I round them up to one decimal point.

Can anyone suggest if any other parameter changes are required in Python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although the coefficients are different, how's the performance? What's the confusion matrix look like? Or are you aiming for explanation and statistical inference?

Comment: Performance is good. My goal here is to replicate the model developed in SAS to Python and compare the intercept and coefficient values which gives me an idea on whether the model development on both platforms is identical. 
The major concern here is that one of the variable has negative coefficient output in Python and positive in SAS. 
Are there any other changes that I should do to Python implementation to resolve the coefficient issue?

Comment: What happens if you exclude the intercept in both cases? Also, what's the shape of your dataset, does it contain categorical variables, does it exhibit any multicollinearity, etc?

Comment: The variables in the dataset do not have any high multicollinearity among themselves or with the target variable. No categorical variables, only numeric and WOE transformed variables are used.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code and the results from SAS and Python Logistic Regression are a match.

```
clf=LogisticRegression(penalty='none',solver='newton-cg',tol=0.00000001)
clf.fit(X, y)
```